# WPF - DataGrid Column with Width="*", but MinWidth to Fit Contents

Tags: wpf, xaml, datagrid, width, datagridcolumn

What would be the best/right way to have a set of `DataGrid` columns have proportional width (`Width="\*"),` but to have their **minimum** width be at least the width of their content? At the moment, if I use `Width="*"`, then the columns stay exactly proportional, but content gets cropped if the columns get too thin. If I use `Width="Auto"`, then the columns size themselves perfectly to their content, but this makes them all different sizes.

What I want is really a combination of the two, like `Width="\*"`, `MinWidth="Auto"` so that when there's extra width the columns will all space out to equal widths, but when the grid is made smaller, the content never gets cropped.

Sadly, `MinWidth="Auto"` doesn't exist, so I guess I need to bind the column's `MinWidth` property, but it's hard to figure out exactly what I would bind it to.

How do I tell WPF `"MinWidth="` the width of the column's widest piece of content?

Comment: Enabling us to set MinWidth="auto" would be a nice feature.

Answer (score 22):

I know its a bit late, but I found your question and programmed a pure-XAML solution.

```
 <ColumnDefinition Width="42*" MinWidth="{Binding Path=ActualWidth, ElementName=projectInfoHeader }"/>
```

Where the `ElementName` points to the control taking up most of the space. Of course thats only possible to do with elements, that do have a limited width.
If you do it for example for a `GroupBox`, than you can resize only to larger width and never resize to smaller one.

If you have several candidates for the value of `MinWidth`, you need to write yourself a `IMultiValueConverter`, which takes an object[], parses it to floats, and returns the maximum (its just 1 linq query if you use it only yourselves and don't need to handle bad usage of the converter)

This way also supports dynamic changing of the `MinWidth`.

Answer (score 13):

Set `Width = "Auto"` in XAML.

Then in the code:

```
MinWidth = ActualWidth
Width = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star)
```

Comment: Worked for me. Loop through all the columns in the grid and execute the code above in all of them. put the loop in a handler for the grid's Loaded event

Comment: took me awhile to figure out even with this help. See my answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13631694/wpf-datagrid-column-width-auto-and-scrollbar

Answer (score 1):

I also had problems to size Grid columns correctly inside the GridViewColumn. There were several things that I tried but then I found the UniformGrid. It was the ultimate solution for me. It just works. I haven't knew it before...seems that it doesn't exist in VS toolbox by default (?) and thus didn't know it even exists.

You can find more about UniformGrid from [here](http://bryanmitchellanderson.com/tag/uniformgrid/).

Answer (score 0):

You can create a dependency property (called e.g. `HorizontalPropFillOfBlankSpace`) for *Grid* control which will ensure what you need (columns with Width="*", but MinWidth to fit contents). Then you can apply it on any grid you want:

```
<Grid namespace:GridHelper.HorizontalPropFillOfBlankSpace="True">
   <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
      <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
   </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
   ...
```

You can see an example of the implementation of this dependency property below. Only columns with `Width="Auto"` are automatically resized to fill gap space. It can be customized by you what you need.

```
public class GridHelper
{
   /// <summary>
   /// Columns are resized to proportionally fill horizontal blank space.
   /// It is applied only on columns with the Width property set to "Auto".
   /// Minimum width of columns is defined by their content.
   /// </summary>
   public static readonly DependencyProperty HorizontalPropFillOfBlankSpaceProperty =
      DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("HorizontalPropFillOfBlankSpace", typeof(bool), typeof(GridHelper), new UIPropertyMetadata(false, OnHorizontalPropFillChanged));

   public static bool GetHorizontalPropFillOfBlankSpace(Grid grid)
      => (bool)grid.GetValue(HorizontalPropFillOfBlankSpaceProperty);

   public static void SetHorizontalPropFillOfBlankSpace(Grid grid, bool value)
      => grid.SetValue(HorizontalPropFillOfBlankSpaceProperty, value);

   private static void OnHorizontalPropFillChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
   {
      if (!(d is Grid grid))
         return;

      if ((bool)e.NewValue)
      {
         grid.Loaded += Grid_Loaded;
      }
      else
      {
         grid.Loaded -= Grid_Loaded;
      }
   }

   private static void Grid_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
   {
      if (!(sender is Grid grid))
         return;

      foreach (var cd in grid.ColumnDefinitions)
      {
         if (cd.Width.IsAuto && cd.ActualWidth != 0d)
         {
            if (cd.MinWidth == 0d)
               cd.MinWidth = cd.ActualWidth;
            cd.Width = new GridLength(1d, GridUnitType.Star);
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Give the column a name in the XAML:

```
<Grid>
      <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
             <ColumnDefinition Width="*" Name="Col1"/>
             <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
      </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
</Grid>
```

Then set the `MinWidth` property in the code as shown below:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    Col1.MinWidth = 340; //enter desired minimum width here
}
```

Comment: you can add Minwidth and Maxwidth as column attribute. No need to add touch the code behind