# How can I set the width of a DataGridColumn to fit contents ("Auto"), but completely fill the available space for the DataGrid in MVVM?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, datagrid

I have a WPF `DataGrid` that contains some data. I would like to set the width of the columns such that the content fits in and never gets cropped (instead, a horizontal scroll bar should become visible). Additionally, I want the `DataGrid` to fill the whole place available (I am working with a `DockPanel`). I am using the following code (simplified):

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Table}">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn MinWidth="100" Width="Auto" Header="Column 1" Binding="{Binding Property1}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn MinWidth="200" Width="Auto" Header="Column 2" Binding="{Binding Property2}" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

This apparently does not work out of the box with `Width="Auto"` as it always looks something like this:

[image: DataGrid: only the first part of the row is marked as "selected"]

This obviously looks ugly. I would like to have the whole row selected, or, which would be much better, the columns to fill the whole width, but as one can see, this does not work.

If I use `Width="*"` instead, the content of the columns gets cropped which is even worse for me.

I found a [similar question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3404067/wpf-datagrid-column-with-width-but-minwidth-to-fit-contents), and a workaround was posted there. This may work, but I am working with the MVVM pattern, so the **ItemsSource gets updated in the ViewModel** and I cannot think about a way of doing it from there, because I cannot access the `ActualWidth` property of the `DataGridColumn`. Also, I would like to do it only in XAML if possible.

I would appreciate any help. Thanks!

Edit: As I still don't have a clue what to do about it, I start a small bounty. I would be very happy about a suggestion what one could do about my problem. Thanks again!

Edit 2: After saus' answer I thought about the options again. The problem is that I need to update the `Width` and the `MinWidth` properties also during the application is running, so not only after loading the window. I already tried to do something like

```
column.Width = new DataGridLength(1, DataGridLengthUnitType.Auto);
column.MinWidth = column.ActualWidth;
column.Width = new DataGridLength(1, DataGridLengthUnitType.Star);
```

in some event that is fired when the underlying `ItemsSource` of the `DataGrid` is updating. However, this does not work, as the `ActualWidth` property does not seem to change after setting the `Width` on `Auto`. Is there an option to somehow "repaint" it in order to get the `ActualWidth` property updated? Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you want to do here. If the Width of the Column gets wider than the `DataGrid` you want a vertical scrollbar and you don't want the text to wrap? Do you mean a horizontal scrollbar? Otherwise, this makes no sense to me but maybe I'm just slow here :)

Comment: Thanks for the hint! Of course I meant a horizontal scrollbar, it would not make any sense otherwise ;-)

Answer (score 36):

I would suggest using the workaround that you linked to. It does work. In the codebehind of your view, add the following to the constructor after InitializeComponent():

```
Griddy.Loaded += SetMinWidths; // I named my datagrid Griddy
```

and define SetMinWidths as:

```
public void SetMinWidths(object source, EventArgs e )
        {
            foreach (var column in Griddy.Columns)
            {
                column.MinWidth = column.ActualWidth;
                column.Width = new DataGridLength(1, DataGridLengthUnitType.Star);
            }
        }
```

I'm assuming that the reason you don't want to use this solution is that you believe that MVVM prohibits code in the codebehind. But since this is entirely view specific logic I believe that it is justified in this case. The whole "MVVM prohibits code in the codebehind" thing is a bit of a misconception.

But if you are bound by style guides, or you want this logic to be available for all datagrids in your app, you can make an attached behaviour that does the job like this:

```
public class SetMinWidthToAutoAttachedBehaviour 
    {
        public static bool GetSetMinWidthToAuto(DependencyObject obj)
        {
            return (bool)obj.GetValue(SetMinWidthToAutoProperty);
        }

        public static void SetSetMinWidthToAuto(DependencyObject obj, bool value)
        {
            obj.SetValue(SetMinWidthToAutoProperty, value);
        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for SetMinWidthToAuto.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty SetMinWidthToAutoProperty =
            DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("SetMinWidthToAuto", typeof(bool), typeof(SetMinWidthToAutoAttachedBehaviour), new UIPropertyMetadata(false, WireUpLoadedEvent));

        public static void WireUpLoadedEvent(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var grid = (DataGrid)d;

            var doIt = (bool)e.NewValue;

            if (doIt)
            {
                grid.Loaded += SetMinWidths;
            }
        }

        public static void SetMinWidths(object source, EventArgs e)
        {
            var grid = (DataGrid)source;

            foreach (var column in grid.Columns)
            {
                column.MinWidth = column.ActualWidth;
                column.Width = new DataGridLength(1, DataGridLengthUnitType.Star);
            }
        }
    }
```

and then for any datagrid that you want to apply this behaviour to, add the following:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Table}" local:SetMinWidthToAutoAttachedBehaviour.SetMinWidthToAuto="true">
```

And then your conscience, as well as your codebehind, will be clear.

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for that! Actually, I don't think that completely view specific stuff should not be in the code-behind. The problem is rather that the content of the `DataGrid` changes in the ViewModel, so the View does not know when it has to call `SetMinWidths` again. Maybe there would be a way that the DataGrid changes as soon as my `NotifyPropertyChanged` method gets called? I think that is the same problem with the attached behaviour, but I will probably find a way to fix that. Will be back with more infos soon. Thanks again!

Comment: see my post, i edited it: Unfortunately, i didn't get it to work like that. For the reasons see above.

Comment: Do we need to unsubscribe that event to avoid memory leaks?

Comment: For me this pattern shrank all the columns to their minimum size, thus it just made the opposite.

Comment: Another flaw of this solution that it makes absolutely unable to edit columns' width.

Comment: Whether there is any solution for unable to edit column's width?

Comment: I found this very useful. I preferred to make the width star sizing proportional to the column's auto size: `column.Width = new DataGridLength(column.ActualWidth / grid.ActualWidth, DataGridLengthUnitType.Star);`

Answer (score 4):

Use a TextBlock with text wrapping inside template column:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Table}">      
    <DataGrid.Columns>          
        <DataGridTextColumn MinWidth="100" Width="Auto" Header="Column 1"
                            Binding="{Binding Property1}" />          
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Width="*" Header="Column 2">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Property2}" TextWrapping="Wrap" />  
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>  
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but I don't want to wrap the text. As mentioned above, I would rather like to get a vertical scrollbar as soon as the text gets too wide.

Comment: The point of templated columns is that you can use whatever control fits your needs inside the DataTemplate, for example <TextBox VerticalScrollBarVisibility=Auto ...>

Comment: i don't want to have a scrollbar in the specific column, but rather one for the whole datagrid which also comes up if i set the width of the columns on "Auto" and the space does not suffice... it would look very bad if you have a scrollbar in every cell...

Answer (score 1):

how about this:

for your columns' MinWidth, you setup a binding to the dataGrid's ScrollContent's Width, with a converter that divide this width by the number of columns

you need some code behind for the converter, but this would keep your MVVM structure intact.

might be a long shot though, did not have the time to try it.

**Edit:** I put some more thought into this and there a pb: it will not work well if you have, say, one huge column and a few small ones. I assumed that all cols are the same width, which is obviously not the case here.

You might want to explore this way though. Using bindings on the Widths with converters is about the only thing I can think of that could work: since you basically have 2 conditions to take into account when calculating a column's width, there will be no easy way to do this.

Comment: okay, thanks for the idea, i will think about that. However, I indeed have one columns that gets much wider than the other columns, so it won't work with the first suggestion. I think you are right that i need to use bindings for the width of the columns (that is what i think as well), but it will still be a challenge to find the right minwidth/width for each column ^^

Comment: it certainly will. ^^  If I may add a piece of advise: don't use the MinWidth property in conjunction with the Width property if you can avoid it. It can lead to massive headache. e.g.: set the minWidth to 100, then the width to 80, and the control's width will be 80: the width takes over the minWidth if you set it by program...

Answer (score 1):

I added the `Event` to the `DataGrid` that redefine their width regarding to the actual width of the `DataGrid`:

```
 private static void OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        DataGrid dg = sender as DataGrid;
        foreach (var column in dg.Columns)
        {
            column.Width = new DataGridLength(dg.ActualWidth / dg.Columns.Count, DataGridLengthUnitType.Pixel);
        }
    }
```

The line:

```
column.Width = new DataGridLength(1, DataGridLengthUnitType.Star);
```

was absolutely senceless. Definition of `DataGridLengthUnitType.Star` shrinks the columns width to their minimum width, and makes their width static and uneditable.

Answer (score 1):

use this for any column you want to fit to its content:
Width = "SizeToCells"

Answer (score 0):

Force the last column to take all the remaining space in datagrid

```
grid.Columns[grid.Columns.Count -1].Width = new 
                  DataGridLength(250, DataGridLengthUnitType.Star);
```