# WPF DataGrid Column Width Auto and Scrollbar

Tags: wpf, xaml, user-interface, width

I have a DataGrid with many columns.

I want `Width="Auto"` with scrollbar showing everything if window narrower than all columns. If window wider I want columns to span empty space so there is no dead space.

Basically I want the column minimum width to fully fit contents or header. And expand to larger if window wider.

Comment: can you post what xaml you have so far?

Comment: If the width is set to auto, the scrollbar never appears.

Comment: @EduardoBrites modified question to add more clarification

Comment: OK. Did you see this answer? http://stackoverflow.com/a/4011435/1132646

Comment: @EduardoBrites actually just found that question, spent over hour on this and couldn't find anything before. I'll remove this question if that solves it

Comment: @EduardoBrites that answer helped, but still took me quit a while to figure out. So I'll post my answer code as answer to this

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In XAML set DataGrid `ColumnWidth="Auto"`

In UserControl constructor add

```
dataGrid.Loaded += (s, e) => { // Column widths
    dataGrid.Columns.AsParallel().ForEach(column => {
        column.MinWidth = column.ActualWidth;
        column.Width = new DataGridLength(1, DataGridLengthUnitType.Star);
    });
};
```

Using this with a custom DataGrid and works great.

Comment: You could also look to the TextRenderer.MeasureText property and set the minwidth equal to it.

Comment: -1 won't compile with standard WPF and .NET 4.5;  not much use to say it works with a **custom** **Datagrid** if the code is not supplied

Comment: -1 also **AsParallel()** is generally a big no no when dealing with GUI elements

Comment: hmm, well worked fine when I was using it, no longer at that company so don't have access to that code anymore.

Comment: @MickyDuncan I got a former colleague to double check and this code is still being used in production and compiles fine there for WPF .NET 4.5. As well as the AsParallel() is appropriate for speed when dealing with many columns which is what the situation was.

Comment: @Brent **AsParallel().ForEach()** will use the [thread pool](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15122756/difference-between-threadpool-queueuserworkitem-and-parallel-foreach). Regarding DataGrid thread safety if I may quote MSDN: _"Any instance members are not guaranteed to be thread safe"_ http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.aspx

Comment: @MickyDuncan you correct there, it may not be thread safe, however the action being preformed in this instance is fine as we know we are the only ones changing these settings at the time this code is exicuted.

Comment: It says that ForEach is not valid to use for datagrid.

Answer (score 28):

In order to "fill" all horizontal space in WPF `DataGrid` as you specified, make sure you have these properties set in **XAML**:

```
<DataGrid 
   HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
   HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" 
   ColumnWidth="*" />
```

Comment: This solution prevents the grid from getting a horizontal scrollbar in the event that it is not wide enough to fit the contents of all columns.