# Difference between ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem and Parallel.ForEach?

Tags: c#, multithreading, windows-services, parallel.foreach, queueuserworkitem

What is the main difference between two of following approaches:

**ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem**

```
    Clients objClient = new Clients();
    List<Clients> objClientList = Clients.GetClientList();

    foreach (var list in objClientList)
    {
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(SendFilesToClient), list);
    }
```

**System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel ForEach**

```
    Clients objClient = new Clients();
    List<Clients> objClientList = Clients.GetClientList();

    Parallel.ForEach<Clients>(objClientList, list =>
    {
        SendFilesToClient(list);
    });
```

I am new to multi-threading and want to know what's going to happen in each case (in terms of execution process) what's the level of multi-threading for each approach? Help me visualize both the processes.

***SendFilesToClient:*** Gets data from database, converts to Excel and sends the Excel file to respective client.

Thanks!

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The main difference is functional.  `Parallel.ForEach` will block (by design), so it will not return until all of the objects have been processed.  Your `foreach` queuing threadpool thread work will push the work onto background threads, and not block.

Also, the `Parallel.ForEach` version will have another major advantages - unhandled exceptions will be pushed back to the call site here, instead of left unhandled on a ThreadPool thread.

In general, `Parallel.ForEach` will be more efficient. Both options use the ThreadPool, but `Parallel.ForEach` does intelligent partitioning to prevent overthreading and to reduce the amount of overhead required by the scheduler.  Individual tasks (which will map to ThreadPool threads) get reused, and effectively "pooled" to lower overhead, especially if `SendFilesToClient` is a fast operation (which, in this case, will not be true).

Note that you can also, as a third option, use PLINQ:

```
objClientList.AsParallel().ForAll(SendFilesToClient);
```

This will be very similar to the `Parallel.ForEach` method in terms of performance and functionality.

Comment: Thanks for detailed explanation @Reed. Two questions: 1) Why is block important (would be great if you can answer in relation to my code)? 2) Further extending the main question, Is there any added benefit of using PLINQ over Parallel.ForEach?

Comment: @Mihir 1) blocking is just different.  The thread you're running will wait for Parallel.ForEach to finish before runnign the next line of code, but the foreach/TP.QUWI code won't wait.  2) No advantage, other than potentially simpler code to understand