# Xaml Xamarin grid column fill with minimum width

Tags: xaml, xamarin, data-binding

I got the (part of a) following grid:

```
<Grid Grid.Row="0" StyleClass="headerBar">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <StackLayout Grid.Column="0" HorizontalOptions="Start" Spacing="0"
                 StyleClass="inGrid" x:Name="titleFreqStacklayout">
        <!-- title / current vessel labels. -->
        <Label StyleClass="header"
            Text="OV Frequentie"/>
        <Label StyleClass="headerSub" Grid.Column="0" x:Name="currentVesselLabel" 
            Text="huidig voertuig label"/>
        </StackLayout>

    <!-- vessel selection button. -->
    <Button Grid.Column="1" HeightRequest="40" Margin="0, 0, 2, 0"
            Text="selecteer voertuig" ClassId="selectVesselButton" x:Name="selectVesselButton"
            Clicked="SwitchViewContent"/>
</Grid>
```

Result:

[image]

problem:

[image]

What I'm trying to achieve is to get the width of the button to fill to the space left, while reserving a minimum width so it doesn't crop beyond the width of the text itself. I found [something similar in WDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3404067/wpf-datagrid-column-with-width-but-minwidth-to-fit-contents) with MinWidth on the ColumnDefinition, but that does not seem to exist in Xaml. I'd love to do this in Xaml, instead of fixing this in the code-behind.

I've tried binding the ColumnDefinitions to the Width, WidthRequest, etc.  and having the first Column fill (like they do in the link above) as follows but it gives an error. XAML:

```
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding Width}" BindingContext="{x:Reference selectVesselButton}"/>
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
```

Error:

> Value is less than 0 or not a number.

Presumably, it's because the value of Width, WidthRequest, etc. is a string (or something) instead of an integer. If this is the way to do it, how would I be able to cast whatever the value type is to int? And if it isn't, How do you do this?

EDIT: I got a temporary solution by setting the column width  to 50% (50*), however, if the text inside the label gets too large, the label seems to reserve two extra white lines. Why does it do this?
What I mean:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could change like this :(define **Grid.RowDefinitions**)

```
<Grid >
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <StackLayout Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0"   HorizontalOptions="Start" Spacing="0"
                         StyleClass="inGrid" x:Name="titleFreqStacklayout">
        <!-- title / current vessel labels. -->
        <Label StyleClass="header"
               Text="OV Frequentie"/>
        <Label StyleClass="headerSub" x:Name="currentVesselLabel" 
               Text="huidig voertuig label "/>
            </StackLayout>

        <!-- vessel selection button. -->
        <Button Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" HeightRequest="40" Margin="0, 0, 2, 0" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
            Text="selecteer voertuig" ClassId="selectVesselButton" x:Name="selectVesselButton" Clicked="SwitchViewContent"
                   />
</Grid>
```

Comment: Setting the row definition to auto only made it so the [button doesn't fill anymore](https://imgur.com/a/O9hIhZj), but this is probably because I'm using Fill rather than FillAndexpand.

Comment: yes，the strange thing is that I initially eliminated the extra two lines of whitespace by adding the row definition attribute,but now don't add that property and there are no extra blank lines,so what's problem now ?

Comment: and `ColumnDefinition Width ` you could change like above,then you don't have to set width to 50%.

Comment: The screenshot above is from the entire grid row. It still reserves those empty whitelines, but the button didn't fill anymore (which I fixed).